# Share on Facebook from the App

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-login

When I tried to `Share on Facebook` through the App, I came across through this issue

```
Error for request to endpoint 'me/photos': An open FBSession must be specified for calls to this endpoint.
```

This is what I tried to do

```
 [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"publish_actions",@"publish_stream",nil]
                                           defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceOnlyMe
                                              allowLoginUI:YES
                                         completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {

                                             [self postImageToFb];
                                         }];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a valid currentAccessToken?

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25256920/how-to-fetch-facebook-user-information-in-ios

Comment: You need to have a accesstoken to make this call, if not found then you have to reestablish a current access token first

Comment: Another thing, your application wont be able to share unless your application has permission for the key `publish_action` for which you got to sent your application for a review process to facebook

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have valid access token and I asked for `public_actions` permission too, but I dont't know why that permission is not granted. This is my session `<FBSession: 0x181422f0, state: FBSessionStateOpen, loginHandler: 0x181f3d00, appID: 1480547465521023, urlSchemeSuffix: , tokenCachingStrategy:<FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy: 0x16d882f0>, expirationDate: 2015-11-07 07:15:56 +0000, refreshDate: 2015-09-08 07:15:56 +0000, attemptedRefreshDate: 0000-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(
    email,
    "public_profile"
)>`. I also noticed the `FBSessionState` value to be 513

Comment: `FBSession`, `access token` and parameters are fine. GraphPath being used is `me/photos`. I couldn't figure out the issue. Thank You.

Comment: If you're testing with a Facebook Account who is not Admin, Developer or Tester of your app, you need to go through Application Review in order for this permission to be enabled for "normal people" who use your app.